# Authenticating a Google Places owner via the API

Tags: google-plus, google-places-api

I am currently developing an app using the Google places API..

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

I want to use the Events methods, so that a Place/Business owner can add events..

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions#event_intro

However I obviously need to restrict it, so that only the Business owner can create events for their Business. Is there anyway of authenticating a user via a Google api, to confirm that they are the Place owner? I looked at Google+ however there is no reference to any 'Places' setup by that user in the people request.

Comment: Nope nothing I'm afraid, the two API's don't seem to link up in any way. The requirement has since been altered so it hasn't been critical for me, It would be good to see an answer though.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like this is possible now. The workflow would be the following:

1. Your user triggers a places search and selects a specific place in the result
2. Your user selects an option in your app to claim they are the owner of your place
3. Your user is redirected into an OAuth flow to Google Places where they login with their Google credentials
4. Once authenticated, your app is provided with an OAuth token for the user
5. Your app submits that token along with a Place reference to a Places API owner verification service
6. The Places API returns a yes/no as to whether the user concerned is the verified owner of the Place

Source - https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3894 - comment #3

Enjoy!

Comment: I haven't tested this myself as the need has since passed, but marking it as correct as it sounds legit.

Comment: @AndyPolhill, doesn't look legit at all to me. The comment being pointing at (it's actually comment #4, not #3) is proposing this workflow, but there's nothing I can find saying anything like it has actually been implemented.